# StopDelay for cars based on variable value (AnyLogic)

Tags: anylogic, modeling

I am trying to stopDelay at delayNucSafe1 (See Screenshot) when the car exits at carMovetoScale1 They way I am currently doing it is at the "On Exit" block of carMovetoScale1  typing: delayNucSafe1 .stopDelay() but I am getting an error that says:
Description: The method stopDelay(Agent) in the type Delay is not applicable for the arguments (). Location: Scale House/Main/carMoveToScale1 - CarMoveTo
[Logic Flowchar](https://i.stack.imgur.com/WHWJl.png)
[where I am asking to stopDelay](https://i.stack.imgur.com/1H9Jh.png)

Can someone help with this?

Comment: What do you want to achieve? There is no apparent need to call that at all, imo. Please clarify, ideally folowing these tips: https://www.benjamin-schumann.com/blog/2021/4/1/how-to-win-at-anylogic-on-stackoverflow

Answer (score 0):

The `stopDelay(Agent)` method is for use when there are multiple agents waiting within the delay and you need to stop the delay for ONE specific agent. If this is the case for you, you would need to know which agent you want to stop the delay for.

For instance, you would call: `delayNucSafe1.stopDelay(delayNucSafe1.get(0))` to stop the delay for the agent at index 0 in `delayNucSafe1`. (This code would also work if there is only 1 agent in the delay).

On the other hand, if you know for sure that there will only ever be 1 agent in the delay (or if you'd like to stop the delay for every agent simultaneously), you would use the method: `stopDelayForAll()`. This method has the benefit that it doesn't need an argument, but it will obviously cause problems if there are multiple agents waiting in the delay, each of which need to be released independently.

So in summary:

```
delayNucSafe1.stopDelay(delayNucSafe1.get(agentIndex))
```

will stop the delay for the agent at index `agentIndex` within `delayNucSafe1`. And:

```
delayNucSafe1.stopDelayForAll()
```

requires no arguments, and will stop the delay for all agents within `delayNucSafe1`